# Geo queries within $lookup pipeline

Tags: mongodb

Hi i have 2 collection area and restaurant
i will fetch distance from each area and fetch restaurant list from restaurant collection according this distance.

```
   db.area.aggregate([
 {
   $lookup: 
   {
     from: 'restaurant',
     let: { distance: "$distance" },
     pipeline: [
       { 
                    "$geoNear": {
                        "spherical": true,
                        "maxDistance": "$$distance",
                        "near": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                77.61546419999999,
                                12.9131813
                            ]
                        },
                        "distanceField": "data.distance",
                        "distanceMultiplier": 0.001,
                        "query":{}
                    }
                },
       },
     ],
     as: 'records'
   }
 }
])
```

but this is not working how I am getting this situation

This area collection data

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609b95d90cc373430554d29d"),
    "data" : {
        "storeid" : ObjectId("60903de5cd97cb204f61f202"),
    },
        distance:5000
    "geopoint" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            77.5717752,
            12.812942
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
}],
```

this restaurant data

```
{"active":true,"name":"test restaurant","geopoint":{"coordinates":[77.6325948,12.9109546],"type":"Point"}}
```

Comment: when I passed like this $$distance MongoDB give error max distance must be a number

Comment: Please provide some parts of your dataset.

Comment: Provide it in the question, a document from the area, and restaurant collection.